# Error - "Class is unavailable : Cannot find Swift declaration for this class", while building app on iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My App has been created under iOS 10.2, and when I'm trying to create a build of the app to run on iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3).

I'm using two frameworks :-

**ViewModelExtensions.framework** (github.com/jozsef-vesza/ExpandingTableView/tree/master/ExpandingTest/Carthage/Checkouts/ViewModelExtensions/ViewModelExtensions)

**ExpandingTableView.framework** (github.com/jozsef-vesza/ExpandingTableView) in my project.

I'm not able to create a built for my project.  Its giving me 3 main errors as follows :-

1. `ExpandingTableViewController` is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class
2. `ExpandingTableViewCell` is unavailable: an not find Swift declaration for this class
3. Use of undeclared type `ViewModelType`

**The thing is its perfectly running on all simulators supporting iOS 10.2. What shall I do ?**

Here is the screenshot.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hAno.png)

My Code - [Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzolC8EgXkB1dU1PZ2hURXo4VnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please add screenshot of the full errors.

Comment: Your question first states that you get get an error while running on an iPhone. Then you claim you can't build your app. That's a contradiction.

Comment: I edited the question as per the need. And No, I have run the app on simulators running on iOS 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

Reason your code not running is because one of the framework you have added Expandable tableView has minimum target requirement specified as 10.2 :) So you can not run it on anything less than iOS 10.2 :)

Now you can't change the frameworks minimum target, so change your projects development target :)

**Solutions :**

Change Development target to 10.2 in your project
 [image]

Or get rid of the framework and find something that has minimum target as iOS 9 :)

Comment: Is there a way where I can make this framework compatible? I need to use this framework

Comment: As am ware of Nope! The framework expandable tableView has its development target set as 10.2 , if you can get the source code of it try changing it to 9 and try running, if works fine then u can create framework of ur own using that project and import it to ur project. Else best solution is to look for other third party frameworks which does the same thing but supports earlier iOS versions. If you can write your own code for what Expandable tableView does then you can get rid of it as well

Comment: @mansi-joshi : Just downloaded the project expandable tableView from GitHub https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/ExpandingTableView. Code is not even compatible with Swift 3 Not sure from where did you get that framework, code in GitHub has development target as 8.3 but it is still in Swift 2 hence not compatible with ur project. Best solution get rid of this framework

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more detail (code, did you use pods, etc.)

However, this looks like a problem with the referenced frameworks (I assume you've imported UIKit at least).  I suspect (without seeing your code) that you're getting errors next to the frameworks above at build time. If so, there are a few things to check:

1. Make sure if you used cocoapods, you are using the '**workspace**' and not the 'project' file.
2. Check and see if your "target membership" (you can see this in the inspector to the right of your class code) is set to the proper targets (i.e. your app - and probably nothing else at this point)?
3. If these checks fail, try re-installing the frameworks (again, depends if you used cocoapods or embedded them via Xcode (point 1 above)).

Comment: I've shared the code. I've not used cocoapods, I've just downloaded the framework and dropped into my project.

Comment: Your frameworks require Deployment Target of 10.2, but you're build settings are set to 9.3.  Change to 10.2 in Targets-General-Deployment Info and it will compile.

Comment: But I want to run it on iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3). Then what shall I do?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Did you download the older simulators that support the 4s? It's not enabled by default in Xcode 8 and iOS 10 doesn't support the 4S.  

Try to see if you can download earlier xcode sims, and also see if you can reinstall the frameworks using cocoapods (which will help keep them updated as well). Google for how, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Found the solution ! Instead of using a framework, I've used its project code and copied the header files into my project. Now my code is running perfectly on the iPhone 4s ! Thank you all for your help !